# Very dense vertical grid ticks for long XTS objects

Tags: r, xts

Prior to updating to xts 0.10, the following code did not have such dense vertical ticks. Obviously the default has changed but I'm unable to get the vertical tick marks to dynamically scale as they seemed to prior to the update. Now when I plot very long series xts objects the vertical ticks are dense enough to obscure the graph.

```
idx = as.Date((Sys.Date()-10000):Sys.Date())
v1 = xts(rnorm(len(idx)), idx)
plot(v1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `major.ticks` and `minor.ticks` arguments.

```
plot(v1, major.ticks = "quarters", minor.ticks = "months")
```